# Laravel Eloquent Save doesn't save

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

I am trying to save survey answers in my db, because of some to me unknown reason the ->save() method is not working, ->update() is working however.

I keep getting the error Array to string conversion every time I try to save.

I have used dd/return/var_dump/print_r whatever would work, to show that it was working up to that step. So now I know it works up to the ->save() method.

My controller:

```php
$array = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        foreach ($array as $survey) {
            $objAns = new Survey_Answer();
            $objAns->name = $survey['surveyName'];
            $objAns->answers = $survey['answersPerQuestion'];

            if($survey['complete'] === true) {
                $objAns['complete'] = 1;
            } else if($survey['complete'] === false) {
                $objAns->complete = 0;
            }
            $objAns->save();
        }

        return;
```

My model:

```php
class Survey_Answer extends Model
     {
      protected $fillable = ['name', 'answers', 'complete'];
     }
```

My migration:

```php
public function up()
     {
        Schema::create('survey__answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
              $table->bigInteger('survey_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
              $table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('surveys')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->json('answers');
            $table->boolean('complete');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I expect the code to save everything that I send along with the $request. This only results in a error: Array to string conversion.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: As it says, you are trying to convert an `array` to `string` while saving it to the database - you can't store arrays into the DB. You have to `implode()` or `json_encode()` it before saving it to the DB.

Comment: Does `$survey['surveyName'];` actually return a string? And is `$survey['answersPerQuestion'];` formatted as json? Could you post the structure of your `$survey`?

Comment: @LucasArbex So you are saying I should json_encode() the $objAns and save that?

Comment: @SilkeNL I am not saying that. I am just pointing out what the error is telling you. As @user931018 said, what is the format of `$survey['surveyName']` and `$survey['answersPerQuestion']`? One of them probably is an `array`, correct?

Comment: @user931018 Yes $survey['surveyName'] does return a string. No $survey['answersPerQuestion'] seems to be an array. {surveyName: "Survey 4",answersPerQuestion: [{question: "Test Question 1",answer: "Test answer 1"},{question: "Test Question 1",answer: "Test answer 1"},{question: "Test Question 1",answer: "Test answer 1"}],complete: true}

Sorry about the spaces and all, to many characters

Comment: So, just `json_encode()` `$survey['answersPerQuestion']` before saving it to the database. However, I should warn you that is probably better to create a relationship between them, instead of saving it like that...

Comment: @LucasArbex Thank you, it indeed worked to encode the answers. Now it correctly saves in the db.

Comment: @SilkeNL Thanks for accepting my answer as an Answer, although I think you should definitely rather look at the other solution provided by Remul since it'll save you from having to convert it to json every time you want to modify your model. The answer I provided is kind of hacky and works as a quick fix but it isn't good for long term use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your `$survey['answersPerQuestion']` in json format not as an array.

```
$objAns->answers = json_encode($survey['answersPerQuestion']);
```

Although as @Lucas Arbex pointed out in the comments, there's certainly a better way to store it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that `$survey['answersPerQuestion']` is an array but you are trying to store it in a json column.

You can use [Laravel's Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) to cast the array to a json string.

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns
>   that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has
>   a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the
>   array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the
>   attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:

Your Model:

```
class Survey_Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'answers', 'complete'];

    protected $casts = [
        'answers' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

> Once the cast is defined, you may access the options attribute and it
>   will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When
>   you set the value of the options attribute, the given array will
>   automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$options = $user->options;

$options['key'] = 'value';

$user->options = $options;

$user->save();
```